# Finding matching values across two sheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Hi I am trying to write a code where checks each value in `column B on Sheet1` and finds the exact matching value in `column A on Sheet 2`, and if a match is found then copies the entire row from `Sheet 2` next to the row with the matching value on `Sheet 1`.

I have the following code (based on an answer I found on SO but when I try to run it it gives `"Next without For"` error, even though there is a `"For x"` to start the loop.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aNumber As Variant
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim rep As Worksheet
    Dim pwr As Worksheet

    Set rep = Sheets("REPORT")
    Set pwr = Sheets("PWRESET")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastrow = rep.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To lastrow    
        aNumber = rep.Range("B" & x).Value       
        Set rng = pwr.Range("A1:A2000")

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)) Then
            rowNum = Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)
        Else
            Next
        End If             
    Next x

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you can just remove the else. The ELSE statement is not a must have. So your loop will continue, if your condition is not fulfilled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bit closer to your goal.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim aNumber As Variant, rowNum As Variant, xfer As Variant
    Dim rng As Range, pwr As Worksheet

    Set pwr = Worksheets("PWRESET")
    Set rng = pwr.Columns(1)

    With Worksheets("REPORT")

        For x = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row

            aNumber = .Cells(x, "B").Value
            rowNum = Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)
            If Not IsError(rowNum) Then
                With pwr
                    xfer = .Range(.Cells(rowNum, "A"), .Cells(rowNum, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value
                End With
                .Cells(x, "C").Resize(UBound(xfer, 1), UBound(xfer, 2)) = xfer
            End If

        Next x

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi this might be working, but how do I edit it so that the matching rows aren't copied on top of the value on the Sheet "rep" but next to it? Like if there is a matching row on "pwr" then copy it to the matching row on "rep" but starting from column "J"? Do I edit (UBound(xfer,1) ?

Comment: ah nvm I edited .Cells(x,"C") so that it pastes the values to column "K", your code is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: You are looking for the values in column B. You stated that you wanted to transfer matching rows 'next to the row with the matching value on Sheet 1' it so I put them starting in `.Cells(x, "C")`. If you want column J then change that to `.Cells(x, "J")`.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't clear enough, anyway your solution works perfectly after some alteration so thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Else Next

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim aNumber As Variant
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim rep As Worksheet
    Dim pwr As Worksheet

    Set rep = Sheets("REPORT")
    Set pwr = Sheets("PWRESET")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    lastrow = rep.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To lastrow    
        aNumber = rep.Range("B" & x).Value       
        Set rng = pwr.Range("A1:A2000")

        If Not IsError(Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)) Then
            rowNum = Application.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)
        End If
    'If your condition is not matched, your code will move on either way... you almost had it ;)         
    Next x

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```